# Forwarding a Django template dictionary to another template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Is it possible to reuse a template dictionary in another view ?

For instance, imagine a view performs a search on the db and provide the search results in a dictionary to a template. The template displays the first 10 results and has a link to display  all the results in another page.

Is it possible to forward the template dictionary containing the search results to avoid having to perform the same search again ?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can't preserve anything across page views - except by storing it somewhere, eg in the session. You couldn't put it in the template itself, as that would then need to be sent back to the server via a POST for the next request.

In any case, there's not much need to do this. If you use the built-in Paginator class to paginate your search, Django will automatically use LIMIT and OFFSET in the query so that only the objects you're actually displaying will be queried.

Comment: I actually use Django-Pagination to paginate the search results. With search results across multiple models, the pagination is messed up when multiple Paginators are on the same page. Hence the idea of displaying the 10 first results for each model with the option to display more results for one specific model on a separate page. So i guess I need to perform the search again :-/